# Serializing/Deserializing case objects with Gson in Scala

Tags: scala, gson

I am using Gson to serialize and deserialize objects, and saving the results in Redis. ie object is serialized into json string then put in Redis, when the object is retreived, it is string then I use Gson.fromjson(str, className) to deserialize into object.

I am beginner with Scala so I assume my usage is incorrect.

I have the following class:

```
case class Status(id: String, state: State)
```

where State is the following:

```
sealed trait State {}

case object COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY extends State {}

case object FINISHED_POLLING extends State {}

case object CURRENTLY_DOWNLOADING extends State {}

case object FINISHED_DOWNLOADING extends State {}

case object CURRENTLY_UPLOADING extends State {}

case object FINISHED_UPLOADING extends State {}
```

I want to serialize `Status` into a json string then deserialize it back into an object.

But, when I serialize `Status` using Gson, I get:

```
"{\"id\":\"foo\",\"state\":{}}"
```

Why is that?

Ex:

```
val Status = new Status("foo", COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY)
```

I expect the serialized output to be

```
"{\"id\":\"foo\",\"state\":\"COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY\"}"
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @ka4eli updated question. I just want to be able to serialize and deserialize using gson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, case objects are serialized by *Gson* to empty json objects: `{}`. You have to write custom serializer to get expected behaviour:

```
object StateSerializer extends JsonSerializer[State] {
  override def serialize(t1: State, t2: Type, jsonSerializationContext: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement = {
    val res = new JsonObject()
    res.add("name", new JsonPrimitive(t1.toString))
    res
  }
}


val gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(classOf[State], StateSerializer)
.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(classOf[State], StateDeserializer).setPrettyPrinting().create()

println(gson.toJson(COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY))
```

Will print:

```
{
  "name": "COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY"
}
```

Also if you want to transform json to case object you have to implement `JsonDeserializer`:

```
object StateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer[State] {
  override def deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): State = {
    val res = json match {
      case o: JsonObject if o.has("name") && o.entrySet().size() == 1 =>
        val name = o.get("name").getAsString
        name match {
          case "FINISHED_POLLING" => FINISHED_POLLING
          case "FINISHED_DOWNLOADING" => FINISHED_DOWNLOADING
          case "FINISHED_UPLOADING" => FINISHED_UPLOADING
          case "CURRENTLY_DOWNLOADING" => CURRENTLY_DOWNLOADING
          case "CURRENTLY_UPLOADING" => CURRENTLY_UPLOADING
          case "COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY" => COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY
          case _ => null
        }
      case _ => null
    }

    Option(res).getOrElse(throw new JsonParseException(s"$json can't be parsed to State"))
  }
}

println(gson.fromJson("{\"name\": \"COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY\"}", classOf[State]))
```

Will print:

```
COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY
```

Comment: would this mean i have to write the serializer for each enum i have?

Comment: also, for deserialize, i cant just do gson.fromJson(String, classOf[Status])?

Comment: updated the answer. Now you have one serializer for all states. Yes, you can't. Because Gson doesn't know that this `{
  "name": "COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY"
}` corresponds to `COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY`.

Comment: life is hard... is there anyway to accomplish this based on the info i posted above? turn value object into string put in redis, then later fetch from redis and parse/deserialize into value object? im not entirely sure if sealed trait is the correct way to go...

Comment: updated answer with deserializer. Now you can everything)

Comment: thank you! this is very helpful. i find it so odd that we gotta jump through so many hoops to get this done...

Comment: Is it possible to serialize into a string instead of as a key-value pair? Basically, I want  `gson.toJson(COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY)` to be just `"COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY"`. Is that possible?